# App crashes when trying to remove sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My app is crashing when I am trying to remove the sprite:

```
  [self removeChild:background cleanup:NO];
```

On this line the app crashes and in the console the error msg is

```
cocos2d: **** WARNING **** CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE is disabled. To improve performance, enable it by editing ccConfig.h
```

when I change the above code to

```
[self removeChild:background cleanup:YES];
```

It works for some sprites but for some sprites it's not working for both cases and the app crashes

Comment: That is not an error message, but a warning given by cocos2d on startup regarding a configuration option you have. It has nothing to do with a crash whilst removing a sprite.

Comment: but my app crashes. when i remove above code then its working fine

Comment: ohhhhh thanks @YvesLeBorg  now i got to know what was the problem.. thanks a lot u right

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign tag for every sprite...then use following code...

```
[self removeChildByTag:tag cleanup:YES];
```